# Is there anyway to way to use an input variable as a function call?

Tags: python, function, variables, web3py

In my current situation, I am trying to build an application that utilizes the Web3.py Python module. The main issue that I am encountering when trying to turn my script into a full stack application is that the function calls in Web3 contracts are not all the same.

For Example:

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io'))
abi_endpoint = 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address='
project_address = '0x8a90CAb2b38dba80c64b7734e58Ee1dB38B8992e'

url = ABI_ENDPOINT + project_address
response = requests.get(url)
response = response.json()
abi = json.loads(response['result'])  

contract = w3.eth.contract(address=project_address, abi=abi)

total_supply = contract.functions.totalSupply().call()
```

I am wanting to be able to put an input variable when I call totalSupply(). The main reason I need to do this is since a lot of the contracts do not have the same function names. For instance, it could be totalApes(), MAX_SUPPLY(), or anything similar. I am just looking for a way to be able to change these things on the front-end rather than having to go change the code every time I am trying to use it.

Comment: you can take input in string and the create a ```map(dict)``` in which key ll be your input_string and value ll be function

Comment: Depending on the type of `contract.functions`, `getattr(contract.functions, 'totalSupply')()` might work fine. It allows you to retrieve an attribute of a class through a dynamic name.

Comment: If you want to pass an input variable to `totalSupply()` you need to change your `totalSupply()` function to accept a parameter.  If you want `totalSupply` itself to be the variable, see above comments.

Comment: You can also resolve a contract function by calling `contract.get_function_by_name('totalSupply')` and then calling the returned function. https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.get_function_by_name

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I work on a smart contract project using Web3.py Python. I hope this helps.

```
def get_from_blockchain(func_name, *args):
  return contract.functions[func_name](*args).call()

def write_to_blockchain(func_name, *args) -> bool:
  tx_hash = contract.functions[func_name](*args).transact()
  tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)

  tx_data = w3.eth.getTransaction(tx_receipt['transactionHash'])
  func_obj, func_params = contract.decode_function_input(tx_data.input)
  print(f"func_obj: {func_obj}, func_params: {func_params}")
  return tx_receipt['status'] == 1

# Read data from blockchain
result = get_from_blockchain('functionName', args1, args2, ...)

# Write data to blockchain
is_success = write_to_blockchain('functionName', args1, args2, ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really addressing your sample code but by the sounds of your question I think looking at this may help?

```
def func1():
    print("foo")

def func2():
    print("bar")

def func3(f):
    f()

func3(func1)#prints foo
func3(func2)#prints bar

#A little more risky

def func4(s):
    f = eval(s)
    f()

func4("func1")#prints foo
func4("func2")#prints bar
```

Note that using `eval` is generally considered a security vulnerability and should only be used in select circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `get_function_by_name()` method together with the exec statement.

For example if you want to loop on the state function `doFoo()` `doBar()` `doBaz()` you would do:

```
for i in ['doFoo','doBar','doBaz']:
    exec(f"var{i} = contract.get_function_by_name('{i}')")
```

You'll get your results in `var_doFoo`, `var_doBar` and `var_doBaz`